# Как сделать эмуляцию COM-мыши на Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, драйвер, com-порт, мышь

Некоторое прикладное ПО (Например, игры) проверяют существование устройства ввода.
(Не совсем правильно так говорить: если вы отправляете SendInput событие, то оно помечается флагом LLMHF_INJECTED, по которому можно понять, что устройства не существует).

Как мне кажется, самым простым способом обойти такое поведение - использование COM-COM петли: к одной подключаться и слать движения и нажатия, второй должен прикинуться мышью.

Где взять драйвер COM мыши (xp, vista, 8.1) (они вообще существуют для чего-нибудь, кроме DOS?) и где прочитать про обмен данными между COM-мышью и компьютером (чтоб симулировать это на питоне)?

Comment: На python если что драйвера не пишут.

Comment: Там предпочтение отдается C и ассемблеру

Comment: Я бы ознакомился с этим проектом, и подумал бы как в нем сделать интерфейс под свои нужды https://github.com/ViGEm/HidGuardian/

Comment: Я не предлагал писать драйвер. Давно (во времена DOS) были COM-мыши (потом они стали PS/2 почти без изменений в протоколе, а уже потом bluetooth/usb/IrDA/RF). Я предлагал поставить COM-петлю (два виртуальных, связанных друг с другом, COM-порта: в один влетело, во второй вылетело) в одну сторону подключить питон, на вторую натянуть драйвер COM-мыши (стандартный) и слать питоном перемещения и клики.

Comment: Большая часть ответа тут. Всем спасибо. habr.com/ru/post/150360/